# Why isn't my write method initialised?

Tags: c

I have been trying to write words that are given by the user in the command shell,but for some reason my program instantly quits after the read() function,so the text in main() :"in main2\n" is never even written. I have been trying to locate my problem for about an hour now and can't seem to find it.

```
# include <stdio.h>

void write_zin(const char* zin,int length_zin){
     const char * runner =zin;
     printf("out of loop\n");
     while(runner!=(runner+length_zin)){
             printf("%c",*runner);
             runner++;
     }
}

void read(char* zin,int NUMBER_LETTERS,int NUMBER_WORDS){
     int i ;
     char woord[NUMBER_LETTERS+1];
     zin[0]='\0';
     for(i =0;i<NUMBER_WORDS;i++){
        printf("Give a word with %i letters\n",NUMBER_LETTERS);
        scanf("%s",woord);
        strcat(zin,woord);  
        strcat(zin,'\0');   
     }
     strcat(zin,'\0');
}


int main(){
    const int NUMBER_LETTERS = 5;
    const int NUMBER_WORDS = 2;
    char zin[(NUMBER_LETTERS+1)*NUMBER_WORDS];
    printf("in main 1\n");
    read(zin,NUMBER_LETTERS,NUMBER_WORDS);
    printf("in main 2\n");
    write_zin(zin,(NUMBER_LETTERS+1)*NUMBER_WORDS);
    printf("in main3\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using the debugger?

Comment: `strcat(zin,'\0');` - what do you expect this to do?

Comment: @ Mitch, I haven't been thought yet at school on how to use a debugger.
@ ecatmur ,add a null after each word

Comment: The `strcat()` function return a pointer to the resulting destination string.

Comment: `write_zin` is a buffer overrun, unless the length is 0. Guaranteed.

Comment: Have you tried compiling that at all? With warnings enabled?

Comment: @SunEric I dont understand how it influences my write function?

Comment: @Deduplicator, no I didn't know you can do that. Ended up with 'implicit declaration of strcat' , I included string.h so that resolved that warning. But it still doesnt work.

Comment: @Burns: Always compile using `gcc -Wall -g -pedantic -std=c99 src.c -o compiled_name` (the `-std=c99` is optional, of course). `-Wall`, `-g` (allows debugging) and `-pedantic` are not, well: not while developing at least

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple errors in your code:

1. Function `void read(char* zin,int NUMBER_LETTERS,int NUMBER_WORDS)`

If you concatenate words separated by `'\0'` you will end having just one string, because   every string function will stop at the first `'\0'` and will not process further  characters. So you cannot use `strcat(zin,'\0');`
 If you want to mark the separation between strings use another special character as `'\n'`   The final function will be:

```
void read(char* zin,int NUMBER_LETTERS,int NUMBER_WORDS){
  int i ;
  char woord[NUMBER_LETTERS+1];
  for(i =0;i<NUMBER_WORDS;i++){
       printf("Give a word with %i letters\n",NUMBER_LETTERS);
       scanf("%s",woord);
       strcat(zin,woord);
   }
}
```

2. Function `void write_zin(const char* zin,int length_zin)`
You cannot ever change the condition of a loop inside a loop. That is what you are doing, because runner is always changing inside the loop, and in addition it is part of your condition.

```
while(runner!=(runner+length_zin)){
         printf("%c",*runner);
         runner++;
 }
```

The final function is:

```
void write_zin(const char* zin,int length_zin){
 const char * runner =zin;
 printf("out of loop");
  while(*runner){
       printf("'%c'",*runner);
       runner++;
 }
```

}